# wp_trim_words() does not work with my code Am I doing any mistake in my code?

Tags: php, posts, functions, permalinks, wp-link-pages

n my WordPress website, I want to show a short text of each blog_post on the custom blog template. I want to show a Read More button with a link to the post at the end so a user can click on that link and view the full post.

But I am always getting the whole post instead of its summary.

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="contentTitle">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
  <div class="contentText">
    <?php 
    $readmore = '<p><a href="'.get_permalink().'"></a></p>';
    echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 3, $readmore ); ?>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Am I doing any mistake in my code?

Comment: Welcome! Code looks correct. Make sure You are checking the right template and Your code is running.